# Implement Signal Slot which update the integeger number

Tags: c++, qt

i try to implement a function which change my integer number for the position , when i press a button and change the position of a drawed circle.

I tried it with a global variable and update the value with a push button, but it didnt work.
Then i tried this and i dont know how to fix this error.
I also tried to include file.moc, but it doesnt work and i work with CMake Version 3.1.0.

> undefined reference to `vtable for Number'

> undefined reference to `Number::onChange(int)'

```
#include <QObject>
    
    class Number: public QObject {
        Q_OBJECT
          Q_PROPERTY( int value READ getValue WRITE setValue NOTIFY valueChanged )
    private:
        int value;
    
    public:
        explicit Number( QObject* parent = nullptr ) :
               QObject{ parent }, value { 0 } {}
           virtual ~Number() {}
    
           int getValue() const { return value; }
    
    
    public slots:
        void setValue(int value) {
            if (value != this->value) {
                this->value = value;
                emit onChange(value);
            }
        }
    
    //public
    signals:
        void onChange(int newValue);
    };
```

```
 void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked() {



    Number a;// a.getValue() == 0, b.getValue() == 0
    Number b;

    a.setValue(5); // a.getValue() == 5, b.getValue() == 0
    b.setValue(48); // a.getValue() == 5, b.getValue() == 48

    QObject::connect(&a, SIGNAL(onChange(int)), &b, SLOT(setValue(int)));

    a.setValue(12); // a.getValue() == 12, b.getValue() == 12
    b.setValue(23); // a.getValue() == 12, b.getValue() == 23


std::cout<<"oben"<<std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Sounds like your make isn't linking in Number.o. Are you building from within Qt Creator?

Comment: How are you using `moc` with CMake scripts? Your bug probably is in your `CMakeList.txt`

Comment: @JosephLarson I use Eclipse

Comment: @dreschejm yes, i realised that and im really new at programming. its the first time my CMakeList.txt bugged

Answer (score 1):

1. Put all your classes in their own .h and .cpp files.
2. Define your inline functions in a .cpp and do a clean rebuild. Make sure all the Qt generated code is removed.

Hope this helped.